# Prove that if $p$ is a prime, then $p^3\mid y^2\implies p\mid y^2\implies p\mid y$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

*Please note that I am requesting a formal proof, using any technique.*

There are two parts in the implication:
(i) if $p$ is a prime, then $p^3\mid  y^2\implies p\mid y^2$, 
(ii) if $p$ is a prime, then $p\mid y^2 \implies p\mid y$.

I know that, as by the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2571635/424260) asked by me : if $p$ is a prime, and $p\mid a^k$ for any natural number $a,k$, then $p\mid a$, but the first part is not obvious from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Partial Hint**

It can be shown that if $p^m | a^2$, then $p^{\lceil m/2 \rceil} | a$. Your consideration here, is the case where $m=1$.

*Edit (Sketch proof)*

Let
\begin{align}
n &= \prod p_i^{n_i} \\
m &= \prod p_i^{m_i}\\
a &=\prod p_i^{a_i}
\end{align}
Then $n | a^2$ means that $n_i \le 2a_i$ or $a_i\ge \lceil \frac{n_i}{2} \rceil$. On the other hand $m | a$ means that $m_i \le a_i$.

If $m$ is as large as possible, $m_i = a_i$ so $m_i =  \lceil \frac{n_i}{2} \rceil $.

Comment: Please give link in MSE, or elsewhere, for its proof.

Comment: @jiten Could not find a link as such, but I have given a little sketch proof of the statement.

Answer (score 2):

It **is** obvious from your first post, because $p\mid p^3\mid y^2$, so that $p\mid y\mid y^2$ is true. Indeed, $p\mid y^k$ implies $p\mid y$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. So, it can be generalized to : for any prime $p, \exists k,n,i,j \in \mathbb{Z+},\,\, k\gt i, n\gt j,\,\, p^k\mid y^n\implies p^{k-i}\mid y^{n-j}\implies p\mid y.$

Answer (score 2):

(i) Since $p\mid p^3$, $p\mid y^2$

(ii) Suppose by contradiction that $ p \nmid y$, but $p \mid y^2$.This implies that $yk=p$ for some integer $k$. But this is not possible since

- We know that $y \neq 1$, it is obvious.
- $k$ is not $1$, since if $k=1$ then $p\mid y$

then $y$ and $k$ are both integers greater than 1, which is not possible since $p$ is a prime. Contradiction! Hence $p$ is a prime. $\ _\square$

Comment: Thanks, but you have proved the failure of converse indirectly (by contradiction), but have not stated this at all. You have actually stated the proof by contradiction of failure of : If $p\mid y^2$, then $p\nmid y$; which is converse of failure of : if $p \nmid y$, then $p\mid y^2$.The reason I am stating this is that you have taken the implication $yk=p$ which can 'directly' arise out of $p\mid y$ only.

Comment: @jiten Thanks for the comment. I have stated that I proved by contradiction now. You said that I 'have taken the implication $yk=p$ which can 'directly' arise out of $p\mid y$ only.' Well, I am not sure what you mean but if you say that $p\mid y \implies yk=p$, I don't think that is true. $p\mid y$ means '$p$ is a factor of $y$' and means $y=pn$ for some integer $n$. What I am trying to say is that since $y$ is a factor of $p$ (since $y\mid p^2$ but $y\mid p$) hence $yk=p$

Comment: Agreed, I was wrong. But, in the last line of your comment you have stated that : "(since $y\mid p^2$ but $y\mid p$) hence $yk=p$."  This line is causing confusion, slrly. your answer for the same cause; as in the answer you have stated that : $p\nmid y$, but $p\mid y^2.$ I request elaborating the same.